Figures and equations numbering in \only - Beamer
While using figures and equation in \only in beamer, they appear to have the same number, and that no increment is done.
I tried the solution provided in figure different numbering \only - beamer, ie to add manually \addtocounter{figure}{1} each time, which works well, but I would like to know if there is an automatic way to do so.
Here you will find a MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>

%% REGLAGES DU BEAMER
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
%%------------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% DOCUMENT %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%------------
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{figure1.png}
\caption{This is Figure 1}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{\insertsection}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{5.5cm}
This is a first column
\begin{itemize}
    \item this is 
    \item some text
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{5.5cm}
\only<1>{
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=1.\textwidth]{figure2}
\caption{This is Figure 2}
\end{figure}
}
%\addtocounter{figure}{1} %%manual increment
\only<2>{
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.\textwidth]{figure3}
\caption{This should be Figure 3}
\end{figure}
}
%\addtocounter{figure}{1} %%manual increment
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{figure4}
\caption{This should be Figure 4}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at our starter guide to familiarize yourself further with our format.

I would use your \addtocounter{figure}{1}  solution, this allows you to easily control in which frames you want this behaviour and in which frames you don't.
Alternatively, you could remove the figure counter from being reset on each overlay:
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>

%% REGLAGES DU BEAMER
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{This is Figure 1}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@overlaycounterresets{}
\makeatother
\resetcounteronoverlays{equation}
\resetcounteronoverlays{parentequation}
\resetcounteronoverlays{footnote}
\resetcounteronoverlays{mpfootnote}
%\resetcounteronoverlays{figure}
\resetcounteronoverlays{table}
\resetcounteronoverlays{ExNo}
\resetcounteronoverlays{SubExNo}
\resetcounteronoverlays{SubSubExNo}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{5.5cm}
This is a first column
\begin{itemize}
    \item this is 
    \item some text
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{5.5cm}
\only<1>{
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=1.\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{This is Figure 2}
\end{figure}
}
%\addtocounter{figure}{1} %%manual increment
\only<2>{
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=1.\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{This should be Figure 3}
\end{figure}
}
%\addtocounter{figure}{1} %%manual increment
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{This should be Figure 4}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

